# How to show in a class diagram that i'm using external API

Tags: api, uml, class-diagram

I'm writing a program that using some of the GoogleMaps API.
How to show this in my class-diagram?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on details, of course, I'd probably do it something like this:

[image]

You might use the `<<External>>` stereotype, you might not.  You might use a fully qualified class name for the Google Maps package (`com::google::googlemaps` or whatever) and/or interface, you might not.

Comment: Nice example. You should remove the "or you might not" parts, though.

Answer (score 2):

1. As an interface.
2. Name it accordingly com.google.*
3. Additionally you can add keywords/stereotypes to decorate the interface with information like "external".
4. Finally, you can package them into different domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reverse the GoogleMaps API in order to get a model. You create another model with your current application and then join both of them into a single model. You can now manipulate both models at the same time in the same class diagram and see views of your structural architecture of your code .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [API2MOL project](https://modeling-languages.com/integrating-apis-in-model-driven-engineering/) whose goal is representing APIs as models. It´s still a prototype but maybe it will help in your case.